I was banned from an online forum. Which law would enable me to force admins to restore my account and issue an apology?
Any way to salvage I was banned from an online forum. Which law would enable me to force admins to restore my account and issue an apology? (and pin my post to homepage) ?
I ask for two reasons. First, nobody brought up applicable anti-discrimination law!

In general, you can be banned from a private business for any or no reason, unless it is because of something not allowed by US law or state law (in the state where the mall is located) such as race, nationality, sexual orientation, etc.

Better for someone to address whether an online forum constitute

"public accommodations," which include retail establishments like shopping malls, cannot discriminate on the basis of "race, color, religion, or national origin."  Some states add additional protected classes.

The better conclusion is that an online forum "can ban you or anyone else for any reason except those protected by law against discrimination." See this Meta SE answer.

There is a circuit split on the issue of whether the ADA
covers
websites,
so certainly in the circuits that hold that the ADA does not cover
websites1 SE is in compliance.
For people with disabilities in circuits that have held that the ADA
applies to websites3, that hurdle is passed. Title III only
applies to certain private entities. A judge would have to be
convinced that SE is one of them, most plausibly a place of public
gathering or
place of public display or
collection. In
addition, the judge would need to be convinced that "the operations of
[Stack Exchange] affect commerce", which shouldn't be too hard, since
they show ads.
rjzii's answer deals
with the practicalities of showing a violation is taking place, should
it get past all the hurdles I've mentioned. It would probably take an
actual instance of someone getting suspended or banned to show
convincingly that SE is not making reasonable accommodations.

1: The Sixth, Ninth, and Eleventh2 Circuits   2: With some
caveats that might not be applicable here.   3: The First and Seventh
Circuits

Second, why are all the linked questions on topic, but not the top one?

public accomodation was addressed: Online places are not public accomodations at all, see my answer to that question.

@Trish pls see edit to my question for a different view.

Nope
It’s a straight up and down request for legal advice by an OP with an exe to grind.
If you want to know about the intersection of this issue and anti-discrimination law, ask that question.
